# Cannot connect to RDS PostgeSQL instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, psql

I have just created a new RDS instance with PostgreSQL but I cannot connect to it. I'm using the following command to connect:

```sh
psql --host=<dbendpoint> --port=5432 --username=<user> --password --dbname=<dbname>
```

I have been searching for information related to the problem, but none of the solutions have worked.

- I have public access to the DB enabled.

[image]

- I have allowed all traffic in the security group of the database.

[image]
[image]

The error I'm getting is this one:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "database-test-1-by-hand.cwsxzm3kzzim.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (204.236.171.212) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any idea about what's happening?

### Update

Here are the options from the VPC the database is on:

[image]

I remember enabling the DNS hostname to allow public access.

### Update 2

I have created an EC2 instance in the same VPC where the db instance is, and I have been able to connect to it.

The db instance is deployed in the same VPC, where I have 4 different subnets, two public and two private. This is the configuration:

[image]

Comment: That screen shot you show doesn't look like anything I see in the security group console.  Is there a missing column?  What port are the rules supposed to apply to?

Comment: Sorry, that's the view of the security group from the database panel. I have added the normal view of the security group (all ports are allowed). I'm aware of the security risk, but first I want to make it work.

Comment: Are you sure you are coming in over IPv4 and not IPv6?  If I specify endpoint by name, I don't really know what it is doing.  Was the IP address on the error message a dotted quartet?

Comment: Yes, it is IPv4. I have updated the error log with the endpoint and the real IP.

Comment: That sounds like it should work.  Was it created as with public accessibility already on, or was that altered later? If altered later, maybe the change to it is still pending?

Comment: It was created with the public accessibility already on. I do not know if I have something at the VPC level blocking the traffic, but I have not seen such thing. I have added those settings.

Comment: Was it launched in a **public subnet** (defined as having a Route Table that points to an Internet Gateway)? Are there any other resources in that same subnet that you are able to access from the Internet?

Comment: I could not select a subnet, I only chose a VPC. In the selected VPC I have two public subnets and two private subnets. I have just created an EC2 instance and I can connect from there to the database. ( I have updated the question with more information)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html This service may be able to help you debug.